# How to create a multiproject in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I want to include My first project "Component1-1-1" inside my second project "Component1-1", I added the following syntax to my setting.gradle file  :

```
include ':Component1-1-1'
project(':Component1-1-1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Component1-1-1')
```

And I added to my build.gradle file :

```
earlib project(':Component1-1-1')
```

It worked fine, but my problem is that I don't understand the  usefulness of ":", I tried to move the ":" , in settings.gradle :

```
include 'Component1-1-1'
project(':Component1-1-1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Component1-1-1')
```

And in build.gradle :

```
earlib project(':Component1-1-1')
```

And everything works fine, I don't know why ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference projects in gradle inside the `project()` functions, you need to qualify the project name, and the delimiter is ':'. Same as '/' in linux.

But when you define a new project with `include()`, you just pass the relative file-path of the project, so no ':'.

Gradle just discards the colon in `include ':Component1-1-1'`.
See the include definition in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/initialization/DefaultSettings.java

and the method "removeTrailingColon" which really should be called "removeLeadingColon".

Comment: Thank you very much @tkruse